# Clear Gnome software counter

Tags: 19.04, gnome-software

After some installation through the Software app, which I don't remember, the headerbar of Software is showing a 1 next to "Installed" as shown.

[image]

How do I clear this number? There's no clear indication as to what "new" software it is referring to.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: The version I have is 19.04.

Comment: I just installed gpicview using the Software Center in a VM of Ubuntu 19.04 (minimal install option), closed the SC and reopened it. I don't see `1` next to `Installed`. Sorry, I'm not familiar with the SC. Maybe you could post in Chat to see if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove the "1" next to installed by purging and reinstalling gnome-software with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center
```